# C# wpf проблема с привязкой бд к панели

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создал и привязал коллекцию `ImageSources` при добавление у меня отображаются изображения, сохраняю как в кеш бд, так и на сервер без проблем так серелизую в json коллекцию, вопрос в том как лучше сделать редактирование публикации, то есть её вложенный изображений.

Так как при удаление изображения из ImageSources, я больше не имею доступа к этим данным, лучше сделать отдельную коллекцию, для хранения id этих изображений до того времени пока изменения не будут сохранены? Обработать события редактирования сразу не могу для бд или отправки на сервер, так как у меня есть две кнопки: `Сохранить` и `Сохранить изменения` то есть все данные сохраняются только после создания или редактирования публикации.

Код для отображения изображений на форме

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="imageItemsControl" Grid.Row="13" Grid.RowSpan="6" Height="65"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,31,20"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImageSources}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image x:Name="ImageAttachment" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageConverter}}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="55" Height="55" Stretch="UniformToFill" MouseUp="ImageAttachment_MouseUp"/>
                            <Button x:Name="DeleteImage" Background="#EF1212" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15" Height="15" Padding="1" Margin="0, 5, 5, 0"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRemoveImage}" FontSize="8" Foreground="White" Click="DeleteImage_Click">X</Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Привязанная коллекция

```
ObservableCollection<ImagePostingDB> ImageSources = new();
```

Модель для работы с данными

```
 public class ImagePostingDB
    {
        [Key]
        public long? Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Изображение в байтах
        /// </summary>
        public byte[]? Image { get; set; }
        public bool Delete { get; set; } = false;
        public bool Add { get; set; } = false;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public long? AutoPostingDBId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public AutoPostingDB? AutoPostingDB { get; set; }
    }
```

Так добавляю изображение

```
 private void BtnSelectImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ImageSources.Count > 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нельзя добавить больше изображений");
                return;
            }
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string imagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
                ImagePostingDB newImage = new ImagePostingDB
                {
                    Id = null,
                    Image = imageBytes,
                    Add = true
                };
                var publish = ListBoxPosting.SelectedItem as AutoPostingDB;
                if (publish != null)
                {
                    using DataContext db = new DataContext();
                    var autoPosting = db.AutoPostingDB.Include(x => x.ImagePostingDB).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == publish.Id);
                    newImage.AutoPostingDB = autoPosting;
                }
                ImageSources.Add(newImage);
            }
        }
```

А так удаляю

```
 private void DeleteImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            Grid grid = (Grid)button.Parent;
            var image = (ImagePostingDB)grid.DataContext;
            ImageSources.Remove(image);
        }
```

А так сохраняю

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Сохраненение публикации
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private async void BtnSavePosting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = GetData();
            if (data.Return)
                return;
            using DataContext db = new DataContext();
            AutoPostingDB autoPosting = new()
            {
                UserSoft = db.UserSoft.FirstOrDefault(),
                Message = TbTextPosting.Text,
                Publish = new DateTime(data.year, data.month, data.day, data.hours, data.minutes, 0)
            };
            await db.AutoPostingDB.AddRangeAsync(autoPosting);
            foreach (var res in ListBoxChatsPosting.Items)
            {
                var chat = res as ListPublishChat;
                if (chat != null)
                {
                    ListPublishChat listPublishChat = new()
                    {
                        AutoPostingDB = autoPosting,
                        ChatId = chat.ChatId,
                        Name = chat.Name,
                        PublishCheck = chat.PublishCheck
                    };
                    autoPosting.ListPublishChat.Add(listPublishChat);
                    await db.ListPublishChat.AddRangeAsync(listPublishChat);
                }
            }
            if (ImageSources.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var element in ImageSources)
                {
                    var tempImage = new ImagePostingDB()
                    {
                        Image = element.Image,
                        AutoPostingDB = autoPosting
                    };
                    autoPosting.ImagePostingDB.Add(tempImage);
                    await db.ImagePostingDB.AddRangeAsync(tempImage);
                    lock (this)
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    ///Присваиваю ID к элементам колекции ImageSources после того как сохранил в бд изображение
                    ///Другого способа не вижу чтобы это реализовать
                    element.Id = db.ImagePostingDB.ToList().Last().Id;
                    element.Add = false;
                }
                var publishDB = await SavePublish(autoPosting);
                if (!publishDB)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Не удалось сохранить публикацию");
                    return;
                }
            }
            lock (this)
                db.SaveChanges();
            var autoPostingID = db.AutoPostingDB.ToList().Last().Id;
            autoPosting.Id = autoPostingID;
            AutoPostings.Add(autoPosting);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Сохранить публикацию на сервере
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="autoPostingDB"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        async Task<bool> SavePublish(AutoPostingDB autoPostingDB)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            string json = JsonPublish(autoPostingDB);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/SavePublish", content);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось сохранить публикацию");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

А так сохраняю изменения код этого места не полностью готовый, не судите строго)

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Сохранение изменений публикации
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private async void BtnEditPosting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using DataContext db = new DataContext();
            var data = GetData();
            if (data.Return)
                return;
            var publish = ListBoxPosting.SelectedItem as AutoPostingDB;
            if (publish != null)
            {
                var autoPosting = db.AutoPostingDB.Include(x => x.ImagePostingDB).Include(x => x.ListPublishChat).Include(x => x.UserSoft).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == publish.Id);
                if (autoPosting != null)
                {
                    autoPosting.Message = TbTextPosting.Text;
                    autoPosting.Publish = new DateTime(data.year, data.month, data.day, data.hours, data.minutes, 0);
                    if (autoPosting.Publish >= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        autoPosting.TbStatusPublish = "Не опубликовано";
                        publish.TbStatusPublish = "Не опубликовано";
                    }
                    publish.Message = TbTextPosting.Text;
                    publish.Publish = new DateTime(data.year, data.month, data.day, data.hours, data.minutes, 0);
                }
                EditImage(db, autoPosting);
                var editPublish = await EditPublish(autoPosting);
                lock (this)
                    db.SaveChanges();
                ListBoxPosting.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }
        void EditImage(DataContext db, AutoPostingDB autoPosting)
        {
            foreach (var iteam in ImageSources)
            {
                if (iteam.Delete)
                {
                    var del = db.ImagePostingDB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == iteam.Id);
                    if (del != null)
                    {
                        autoPosting.ImagePostingDB.Remove(del);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (iteam.Add)
                {
                    var tempImage = new ImagePostingDB()
                    {
                        Image = iteam.Image,
                        AutoPostingDB = autoPosting
                    };
                    autoPosting.ImagePostingDB.Add(tempImage);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Сохранить изменения публикации на сервере
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="autoPostingDB"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        async Task<bool> EditPublish(AutoPostingDB autoPostingDB)
        {
            autoPostingDB.ImagePostingDB = ImageSources.ToList();
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            string json = JsonPublish(autoPostingDB);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/EditPublish", content);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось сохранить публикацию");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Вы сам себе злобный буратино. Вам WPF такой "Ей, давай я все сделаю сам", вы ему "Нет, пошел вон, я  сам!", а он "ну пожалуйста!", вы "нет!".. Вы и XAML проигнорировали, и привязки, и вообще здравый смысл. В итоге ваш код из пары строк превратился в это... Дайте свободу своему проекту, пусть он сам все создает, привязывает, очищает, удаляет, и так далее, не пишите XAML через код, и будет у вас работать все как положено. И о какой "проблеме привязки" идет речь, если у вас 0 привязок в коде? Короче, увы, но вы сделали максимально все доступные ошибки, которые только можно сделать в WPF...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ при изменение коллекции я привязываю  контекст
`// Добавляем кнопку на элемент Image
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.DataContext = item;`
 И вопрос написал с тем учётом что не понял как правильно реализовать это.

Comment: Указать `DataContext` - это не привязка. Привязка, это условно `DataContex = this;`, где `this` - некий класс, с публичными свойствами, в котором делаете например `public ObservableCollection<Item> Items {get;} = new(){ new Item(...) }`, ну и дальше **в XAML** `<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}"/>`, все, у вас базовая привязка, где данные лежат в коллекции `Items`, они автоматически отображаются на экране с нужным видом, они автоматически обновляются при добавлении/удалении. Ну и теперь внимание на ваш код, где хоть один `ItemsSource` или `Binding`?

Comment: `с тем учётом что не понял как правильно реализовать это` - скажите сейчас только честно, вы хотите понять как правильно, или вы очередной студень, у которого на носу сдача, и ему без разницы как выглядит его код, лишь бы сдать. Только честно, ибо мне тоже как-то не хочется тратить свое время в пустую. Если хотите, вам это нужно, то жду от вас **подробное** описание задачи, что должно быть, как должно отображаться, работать, и так далее, напишу вам вечером подробный пример. Если нет, чтож, ждите, мб кто-то решит покопаться в ваших костылях.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ про привязку понял. Я не студент, я вообще не учился на программиста, код из вопроса я мог добить костылями и заставить его работать, но как по мне это как минимум не правильно, избыточно в подходе и как то костыльно,  и поэтому написал вопрос со всем кодом и описанием. Спасибо за наставление. Исправлю код на основе текущих замечаний и обновлю вопрос, так как проблема с id врятли решится исправив только wpf. Но в обновленном вопросе распишу что нужно, более детально

Comment: @EvgeniyZ обновил вопрос и код

Comment: Вы до сих пор не описали свой проект. Вот я хочу показать как подобное написать по всем правилам, думаю вам полезно такое будет, но вот что писать - для меня до сих пор загадка, ибо я вижу лишь панель, картинки, базу, кнопки, все, а вот что должно делать приложение, я не вижу. Касательно кода выше и проблем: 1. У вас до сих пор нет привязки, ибо как я написал ранее "публичное свойство", это `ObservableCollection<ImagePostingDB> ImageSources` - приватное поле, публичным оно будет тогда, когда будет `public` в начале, а свойством, когда будет иметь как минимум `{get;}`.

Comment: `Обработать события редактирования сразу не могу` - вот тут не понял, что мешает все отредактировать, а потом вызвать один раз `db.SaveChanges()`? Или вы удаленный объект можете "восстановить"?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ код написал  в вопросе весь на клиентской части для работы с изображениями. Суть в том что есть список, список содержит вложения-картинки. При выборе из списка я отображаю изображения их можно удалить, добавить, отредактировать публикацию. Когда редактирование завершено, то по нажатие кнопки сохранить изменения мне нужно, чтобы картинки которые для публикации были добавлены были отправлены, с этим нет проблем. 
А картинки которые были удалены, мне нужно отправить их id на сервер чтобы удалить их из базы. То есть мне нужно в одном запросе слать картинки и id того что надо удалить

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `вот тут не понял, что мешает все отредактировать, а потом вызвать один раз db.SaveChanges()?` Вот этого я и добиваюсь чтобы при нажатии кнопки сохранить, сохранить все в кеш и на сервере

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `У вас до сих пор нет привязки` При добавлении в коллекцию у меня все добавляется, при удаление из коллекции тоже работает. ItemsSourse у меня привязан к этой коллекции.

 А свойства для коллекции или делать его публичным, не совсем понимаю зачем это нужно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  `а вот что должно делать приложение, я не вижу` это клиент для веб апи, логика на стороне сервера вся будет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и целесообразно хранить id одинаковые для картинок как у клиента так и в базе на сервере?  Которые генерирует ef. Задумался над тем что в таблице `ImagePostingDB`  при добавление картинки собьется целостность id у одного и второго пользователя. В таком случае как правильнее помечать картинки для пользователей? На уровне приложения генерировать id, но тогда при перезапуске приложения этого не будет в памяти, тогда лучше эти id'шники тоже кешировать? С веб апи мало работал, теперь понял что логика с id у меня точно не правильная.

Comment: Хотя кажется надо просто сохранять на сервере изображения, брать их id и ответе сервера для изображений сохранять эти id и будет уникально это для каждого пользователя.

Comment: Так `при добавлении в коллекцию у меня все добавляется` - значит вы используете публичные свойства, привязка к привату, и полям невозможна. `логика на стороне сервера вся будет` - если весь этот код будет на стороне сервера, то зачем серверу что-то ждать, следить за клиентскими действиями (добавил, удалил, и так далее)? Сервер должен получить запрос по типу "Удали картинку", в ответ он моментально должен дать ответ "Картинка удалена" или "Картинки не существует", эту информацию обрабатывайте на клиенте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `эту информацию обрабатывайте на клиенте.` у меня есть также кеш бд на стороне клиента, сохраняются данные как у клиента так и на сервере, только проблема с id изображений была так как для удаления нужно было собрать id что удаляем и потом при изменение отправить эти id на сервер. С изображениями решил так, есть привязанная коллекция где обрабатываю добавляемые файлы, а удаляемые сохраняю в другую коллекцию именно id что надо удалить. И потом при нажатии кнопки склеиваю эти коллекции и шлю на сервер.

Comment: Конечно это не решило проблему с id так как я для клиента беру с бд сразу, а надо брать в ответе от сервера, то есть сервер сохранил\прислал в ответе id и только потому у клиента id давать изображениям, в этом была моя ошибка

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `привязка к привату, и полям невозможна` это знаю, с json\рефлексией\ef аналогично что только `public` и как минимум `{get;}` надо ставить чтобы был доступ извне